# Pass data between view controllers

Tags: swift

i'm trying to pass data between viewcontrollers with value is slider's value but it's not work.
here's my code
[ViewController1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgUXU.png)

[ViewController2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPrx6.png)

Comment: You need to add code instead of adding image of code,

Comment: Also you need to pass String instead of slider value `performSegue(withIdentifier: "dataPass2", sender: simpleString)`.

Comment: Try this `destination.myString = "\(sliderView.value)"`

Comment: Thanks. It's work now !

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your screen shot, I would suggest you to assign `simpleString` value to `destination.myString`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always fail because you are trying to cast from a Double to a String. Doing this in Swift gives the following message:

> Cast from 'Double' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

What you need to do is have the line of code changed from:

```
 destination.myString = sender as? String
```

to:

```
 destination.myString = String(format:"%f", sender)
```

or

```
 destination.myString = "\(sender)"
```